# Getting TypeError: EC is not a constructor running pab-nami

Tags: nami-wallet, plutus-pab, pab

When running npm, start inside a nix-shell of plutus-apps/plutus-pab-executables/demo/pab-nami/client

Comment: Actual steps would be helpful here so that the advice is crystal clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. There's a bug open internally for this.
In future, it's best to raise questions here and bug reports over in the [plutus-apps](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps) Github repo. I've also raised it there now: [#357](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/issues/357)